# Problema al centrar con padding equitativo barra de iconos con redes sociales

Tags: html5, css3

Estaba haciendo una pagina y en mi `footer` tengo una barra de redes sociales con forma circular y un borde, quiero que los textos de las redes sociales me queden centrados y con espacio hacia los cuatro lados y que se vean de forma equitativa, bien, para lograr el espaciado estoy usando `padding` sin darle ancho ni alto al contenedor que tiene los enlaces de las redes sociales.

El problema es que los espacios izquierdo y derecho no me quedan equitativos y eso es muy notable en el primer icono de redes sociales, se supone según yo que el `padding` debería dejar a todos los iconos con espacios equitativos y deberían verse de igual tamaño y centrados (esto ultimo si lo logre hacer)

podrían darme alguna recomendación de como hacer mi `css` para lograr el objetivo que tengo en mano, a continuación compartiré mi código:

**CÓDIGO**

```css
.list-without-styles{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-list{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item-list{
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 0.5em 0.4em;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Aerolinea Airbn">
</head>

 <body>
 <!--AQUI VA MI FOOTER!-->
 
     <div>
        <div class="container">
            <footer class="row column-direction center-footer-content color-footer-text">
                 <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                        <ul class="list-without-styles flex-list">
                            <li class=" margin-list-item item-list">
                                 <a href="#" > 
                                 <span class="fa fa-facebook color-footer-text"></span>
                                 </a>
                             </li>
                            <li class=" margin-list-item item-list">
                               <a href="#">
                               <span class="fa fa-twitter color-footer-text"></span>
                               </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class=" margin-list-item item-list">
                                <a href="#" >
                                <span class="fa fa-google color-footer-text"></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class=" margin-list-item item-list">
                                <a href="#">
                                <span class="fa fa-pinterest color-footer-text"></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                         </ul>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
  </body>
 
</html>
```

Espero y puedan echarme una mano, como podrán ver algunos quedan mas gorditos que otros y no se como hacer que queden igual y al mismo tiempo la solución sea escalable, porque intente dándole mas `padding` a unos que a otros pero bueno eso es meter el autobús un poco...

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con darle un ancho y alto fijo, luego centra todo los elementos con ayuda de `display: flex`

```css
.list-without-styles{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-list{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item-list{
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Aerolinea Airbn">
</head>

 <body>
 <!--AQUI VA MI FOOTER!-->
 
     <div>
        <div class="container">
            <footer class="row column-direction center-footer-content color-footer-text">
                 <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                        <ul class="list-without-styles flex-list">
                            <li class=" margin-list-item item-list">
                                 <a href="#" > 
                                 <span class="fa fa-facebook color-footer-text"></span>
                                 </a>
                             </li>
                            <li class=" margin-list-item item-list">
                               <a href="#">
                               <span class="fa fa-twitter color-footer-text"></span>
                               </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class=" margin-list-item item-list">
                                <a href="#" >
                                <span class="fa fa-google color-footer-text"></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class=" margin-list-item item-list">
                                <a href="#">
                                <span class="fa fa-pinterest color-footer-text"></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                         </ul>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
  </body>
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola he estado mirando tu codigo y he modificado las clases en el div con `class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3"` a `<div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">` para centrar la lista a lo ancho de la pagina, en cuanto a los estilos con darle un ancho y centrar el texto de `.item-list` valdria.
Tu codigo quedaria asi:

```css
.list-without-styles{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-list{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item-list{
  width: 2.8em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Aerolinea Airbn">
</head>

 <body>
 <!--AQUI VA MI FOOTER!-->
 
     <div>
        <div class="container">
            <footer class="row column-direction center-footer-content color-footer-text">
                 <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                        <ul class="list-without-styles flex-list">
                            <li class=" margin-list-item item-list">
                                 <a href="#" > 
                                 <span class="fa fa-facebook color-footer-text"></span>
                                 </a>
                             </li>
                            <li class=" margin-list-item item-list">
                               <a href="#">
                               <span class="fa fa-twitter color-footer-text"></span>
                               </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class=" margin-list-item item-list">
                                <a href="#" >
                                <span class="fa fa-google color-footer-text"></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class=" margin-list-item item-list">
                                <a href="#">
                                <span class="fa fa-pinterest color-footer-text"></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                         </ul>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
  </body>
 
</html>
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos